# Using Linq to get XML data from database

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm struggling to get the values of a single xml node using Linq.

Here is my XML.

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <record>
       <AddressLine1>abcd street</AddressLine1>
       <AddressLine2>xyz AVE</AddressLine2>
       <AddressCity>Illinois</AddressCity>
       <AddressState>Chicago</AddressState>
       <AddressZip>23434</AddressZip>
       </record>
```

And here is my c# code

```
    XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Parse(varQ.Content);
       //When I debug I find that xmlDoc contains the XML. So that is alright.

    var q = (from lpi in xmlDoc.Descendants("record")
            select new { AddressLine1 = lpi.Element("AddressLine1").Value,
            AddressLine2 = lpi.Element("AddressLine2").Value,
            AddressCity = lpi.Element("AddressCity").Value,
            AddressCountry = lpi.Element("AddressCountry").Value,
            AddressState = lpi.Element("AddressState").Value,
            AddressZip = lpi.Element("AddressZip").Value,
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

var q shows null. Can u  please help me find out what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Descendants on DescendantsAndSelf:

```
 string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
       <record>
       <AddressLine1>abcd street</AddressLine1>
       <AddressLine2>xyz AVE</AddressLine2>
       <AddressCity>Illinois</AddressCity>
       <AddressState>Chicago</AddressState>
       <AddressZip>23434</AddressZip>
       </record>";

            XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Parse(xml);
            var q = (from lpi in xmlDoc.DescendantsAndSelf("record")
                     select new
                     {
                         AddressLine1 = (string)lpi.Element("AddressLine1"),
                         AddressLine2 = (string)lpi.Element("AddressLine2"),
                         AddressCity = (string)lpi.Element("AddressCity"),
                         AddressCountry = (string)lpi.Element("AddressCountry"),
                         AddressState = (string)lpi.Element("AddressState"),
                         AddressZip = (string)lpi.Element("AddressZip"),
                     }).FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(q);
```

Print:

```
{ AddressLine1 = abcd street, AddressLine2 = xyz AVE, AddressCity = Illinois, AddressCountry = , AddressState = Chicago, AddressZip = 23434 }
```

Link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fXQivX

Comment: I'll try and get back to u. Thanks for replying. :)

Comment: I get a null reference exception (System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Comment: Another error:  Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: element

Comment: @Ashwini Nayak, show how you have changed the request

Comment: It worked finally. Apparently I had some more elements in the XML in datetime, bool, long,decimal etc whose values needed to be fetched. Casting to eg. (decimal?) instead of (decimal)  did the work for me.. Thanks for your help Foggy Finder :)